# Скрипт на vbs для перехода по ссылке

Tags: vbscript

Хочу создать скрипит VBS, чтоббы сначала выводилось окно "перейти по ссылке?" и внизу кнопка да и кнопка нет. При нажатии Да открывается сайт допустим [www.site.com](http://www.site.com). при нажатии нет и при закрытии окна ничего не происходит.

Относительно сообщения я имею некоторые догадки, а с сайтом - хз. браузер MS Edge

Comment: То есть, Вы хотите, чтобы при заходе на любой сайт при нажатии на любую ссылку сначала появлялось окно, а потом, в зависимости от ответа пользователя, происходил или не происходил переход по ссылке?

Comment: Вы меня поняли максимально точно

Answer (score 0):

А я бы эту задачу решал при помощи плагина к браузеру...

его задача - подменять <a href="URL" ... > на <a href='ByClick(URL); return false;' ... >

А функция `function ByClick(URL){ ... }` как раз и задаёт вопрос о том, переходить ли по ссылке.

Понятное дело, что VBS - наверное, является в этом случае не очень релевантным.

Потому что такие штуки удобнее делатьна JS.

Мне даже приходит в голову один плагин, который решает подобную задачу, называется *Stylish*

Он позволяет заменить любой класс в стилях и описать любое поведение, перекрывающее свойства в станице. Например, можно описать, что у тега `<body>` **всегда** будет `background color=#FFF;` - что то в таком духе.

Правда, штука довольно головоломная, я пользуюсь её раз в несколько лет, и каждый раз полдня уходит на то, чтобы понять, что там и как делать. Но результат неизменно радует!

И еще - я не пробовал в Sylish экспериментировать с подстановкой JS - скриптов. Это интересный эксперимент, не спорю, и, возможно, я его когда нибудь поставлю. Прямо сейчас - немного занят...

Если даже этот эксперимент не увенчается успехом - можно написать своё расширение к браузеру. Делается этоне сложно, достаточно взять дефлтный пример расширения ми чуть чуть его дополнить.